# Interface with subProject

Tags: vb.net, interface

Hy, Can I create an interface with a sub-project?

```
Public Interface IDraft
    Property LienVue() As String
End Interface
```

```
Public Class C2018

    Implements IDraft

    Private m_LienVue As String

    Sub New(Optional ByVal LienVue As String = "")
        m_LienVue = LienVue
    End Sub

    Property LienVue() As String Implements IDraft.LienVue
        Get
            Return getlienvue()
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_LienVue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function getlienvue() As String
        Return "xxxxxxxx"
    End Function
End Class
```

The c2018 class is in a sub-project of my main project. The goal is to add a reference to a different API from the main project

Comment: Of course you can. Every time you implement a standard .NET interface, e.g. `IDisposable`, you're doing just that. Just as is always the case, if you want to use a type declared in a different assembly, you need to reference that assembly. If the two projects are in the same solution, you can reference the project rather than the compiled DLL.

Comment: but in the c2018 class I have the message 
BC30002: Type '<typename>' is not defined

Comment: Again, it's just like any other type. Assuming that you have referenced the project/assembly, you also need to specify the namespace the type is a member of. You can do that either by qualifying the type name where you use it or importing the namespace, either at the project or file level. The root namespace for a project defaults to the project name, but you can change that in the project properties if you want.

Comment: thanck for your help